# Express API with mongo under docker, querying issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, curl

I have an API (express) using a mongodb - everything in docker.

I'm using `curl` to get some data, it works well with low amount of data

`curl localhost:8000/api/lowdata`

But once I hit big data apis, the `curl` command returns `Empty reply from the server`, if I try to directly re-run the curl I get this error `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

This is my 'big data api' which should return 1.6 million objects :

```
api.get('/bigdata', async (req, res) => {
    let data = await BigData.find().lean();
    return res.json(data);
});
```

The node server doesn't seem to restart (checked `docker logs`), so I have no idea of what's going on...

Comment: 1.6M objects?! Please use steams and use `res.pipe()`

Comment: I feel the docker container is running out of memory while serving array 1.6M objects in one shot

Comment: @AnandUndavia I'll check this out

Comment: @AnandUndavia could you provide some code snippet on how to get the stream working?

Comment: @AnandUndavia I got it working with the stream, if you post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: It's okay. You can answer your own question and mark it accepted so that it can be helpful for others. Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to directions given by @AnandUndavia, I managed to get it working using stream API :

```
api.get('/bigdata', async (req, res) => {
    Bigdata.find()
        .lean()
        .cursor()
        .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
        .pipe(res.type('json'));
});
```